# Set width and height of image in php

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I migrated a static site to WordPress, I created a custom PHP template and on the old site I was able to set the image width and height in PHP, now it doesn't work no matter what I change.

Can someone help me fix my code?

My goal is to create a bar chart using the variable as the width of the image.

```
for($n=$lYear; $n >= $fYear; $n--){
    $pCent = $avg[$n]/$hAvg;
    print("<tr>");
    print("<td>$n</td>");
    print("<td>&nbsp;</td>");
    $avgString = sprintf("%01.2f", $avg[$n]);
    print("<td align=right>$avgString</td>");
    print("<td align=center>&nbsp;</td>");
    $pixW = ($pCent*516)-16;

    echo('<td><img src="../dev2016/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/redbar.gif" 
                                               width="$pixW" height"16" />');
```

Comment: Are $avg and $hAvg being defined somewhere? Are you getting any error messages?

Comment: `echo('<td><img src="../dev2016/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/redbar.gif" width="' . $pixW . '" height"16" />');`

Comment: I'm not getting any errors, the variables are defined in the code that isn't displayed in the snippet.

Comment: Does anyone know how to fix this? I can't figure out why the height is not being recognized even when I only set the height of the image the code still ignores it. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Issue is with enclosing echo content in single quotes.
If you want to use a variable, always enclose in double quotes.

Try this 
    `echo("<td><img src='../dev2016/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/redbar.gif' width='$pixW' height='16' />");`

Answer (score 0):

Your PHP code doesn't realize that there is a variable being called in your html. You need to escape the quotes so that the variable gets treated like a variable and not another piece of text.

```
echo('<td><img src="../dev2016/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/redbar.gif" width="' .$pixW. '" height"16" />');
```

No offence intended but here is a link to W3 that illustrates the point

http://www.w3schools.com/php/showphp.asp?filename=demo_echo2

**Edit to reflect comment**

You need to have a space between the single quotes and your variable. With your height it's in there as 
     height="'.$pixH. '" but it needs to be height="' .$pixH. '"

Comment: Thanks, your suggestion worked for the width but the height is being ignored now. Here is what I tried: for($n=$lYear; $n >= $fYear; $n--){
    $pCent = $avg[$n]/$hAvg;
    print("<tr>");
    print("<td>$n</td>");
    print("<td>&nbsp;</td>");
    $avgString = sprintf("%01.2f", $avg[$n]);
    print("<td align=right>$avgString</td>");
    print("<td align=center>&nbsp;</td>");
    $pixW = ($pCent*516)-16;
    $pixH = .01;

 print('<td><img src="../dev2016/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/redbar.gif" width="' .$pixW. '" height="'.$pixH. '"  />');
    print("</tr>");

Comment: @NetAdmin1 have a look at the comment I made in my original answer and see if that helps at all

Comment: your height variable is set to .01 but initially your html code had it set to 16? I'm grasping now because at this point your syntax looks right

Comment: I was playing with the height but it wont change at all.